# iPhone application as HTTPS server

Tags: ios, https, webserver, ota

I am trying to achieve Over the Air access to the files of iPhone. As per my requirement I need to make a device as an HTTPS server. After googling, I come across some cool stuffs to make iPhone as Webserver, all of them are acting as HTTP server.

Does anyone know how to create an HTTPS Server inside iPhone Application?

Answer (score 0):

I did not use this myself, but google was very sure this is the solution to you problem:

https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer

Comment: I gone through this. but not able to achieve the result. Do you have some snippet to show?